# How to store only the first element in python

Tags: python

I am dealing with a large txt file (1,000,000 elements), for example:

```
tammy_wynette    band
tammy_wynette    artist
tammy_wynette    musical_artist
tammy_wynette    group
tammy_wynette    person
tammy_wynette    agent
tammy_wynette    organisation
mansion_historic_district    architectural_structure
mansion_historic_district    place
mansion_historic_district    building
joe_sutter    person
joe_sutter    agent
```

What I want to get is only the first element for each item:

```
tammy_wynette    band
mansion_historic_district    architectural_structure
joe_sutter    person
```

I use dictionary, but my code is very slow:

```
dicCSK = {} 
for line in fin:
    line=line.strip('\n')
    try:
        c1, c2 = line.split("\t")
    except ValueError: print line
    if c1 not in dicCSK.keys():
        dicCSK[c1]=c2
        fout.writelines(c1+"\t"+c2+'\n')
```

Is there any quick way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do `if c1 not in dicCSK:` instead of `if c1 not in dicCSK.keys():`. If you're using Python 2.x [`keys`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) will return keys as a list which means that they would need to be checked sequentially.

If you're not using the values later you might as well use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) instead:

```
dicCSK = set()
for line in fin:
    line=line.strip('\n')
    try:
        c1, c2 = line.split("\t")
    except ValueError: print line
    if c1 not in dicCSK:
        dicCSK.add(c1)
        fout.writelines(c1+"\t"+c2+'\n')
```